# Get row counts for different lookup values

Tags: sql, sql-server

A temp table has 700+ records with a PK. 12 columns contain Id values from lookup tables.  Each lookup table has 4-8 records in it.  How can I get a record count for each Id value in table LookupA that has a relationship via the PK to Id values in every other lookup table?  Each lookup value in each lookup table needs to compared for a record count to every other lookup table and value.

I can write a SQL statement to get specific values for specific columns, but that's a long exercise and will slow down the proc.

Here's a sample of the data.

```
PK   LookupA    LookupB    LookupC
1       1          1          3       
2       1          2          3
3       1          3          2
4       2          4          2
5       4          1          1
6       3          2          1
7       2          3          3
8       4          4          3
9       4          3          2
10      1          1          2
```

The results need to compare LookupA with LookupB and LookupC to get a row count.

```
Table    Value    LookupB 1  2  3  4     LookupC 1  2  3
LookupA    1              2  1  1  0             0  2  2
           2              0  0  1  1             0  1  1
           3              0  1  0  0             1  0  0
           4              1  0  1  1             1  1  1
```

Then LookupB would be compared to LookupA and LookupC.
And LookupC would be compared to LookupA and LookupB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With this code you can get the numbers for all combinations of A,B and C in pairs:

```
select 'A-B' as Combination, LookupA, LookupB, count(*) as NumRecords
from table
group by Combination,LookupA, LookupB
UNION       
select 'A-C' as Combination, LookupA, LookupC, count(*) as NumRecords
from table
group by Combination,LookupA, LookupC
UNION       
select 'B-C' as Combination, LookupB, LookupC, count(*) as NumRecords
from table
group by Combination,LookupB, LookupC
```

After this, if you want to see all the values for LookupA comparing to B and C just 
look for Combinations A-B and A-C

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, your temp table contains foreign keys to other tables, so why not simply use joins? Something like this.

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT lookupA.id) as CountA
  , COUNT(DISTINCT lookupB.id) as CountB
  , etc...
FROM #temp_table t
LEFT OUTER JOIN lookupA a on a.id = t.lookupA
LEFT OUTER JOIN lookupB b on b.id = t.lookupB
...etc
```

I would suggest reviewing the design if possible. Having so many small tables complicates things, is it not possible to consolidate this and just have one lookup table? You could have an additional field "LookupType" and all the lookups could be in the same place which would make retrieval much simpler.

Answer (score 0):

I used a slight derivative of the statement below without any UNIONs to get me where I wanted to go.

/*
 select 'A-B' as Combination, LookupA, LookupB, count(*) as NumRecords
 from table
 group by Combination, LookupA, LookupB
*/

I used a variable and a WHILE loop to place the various summaries where they need to be.